# ASP.NET Core 5.0 Razor page Deployment in Windows server 2012 R2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, iis

I have created a razor page in asp.net core web app (.Net 5.0) and all works fine in my development machine. Now I have to deploy it in my test server which is windows server 2012 R2 version.

I Installed the ASP.NET core bundle version 6.0 in the test server and restarted my machine. I have the publish folder from the development machine. All I have is to copy those files to the test server.

Now I go to the IIS server and see the list of application pools and I dont see .Net 5.0 or .Net 6.0.

I have the following list of application pools

```
 .Net 4.5 
 .net 2.0,
  .net 2.0 with classic,
  ASP.NET 4.0
  ASP.NET 4.0 CLASSIC
```

but nothing related to .Net core or .Net 5.0

Even if i create a new application pool in IIS server it shows only

```
.Net CLR 2.0 

.Net CLR 4.0 

No Managed code
```

How will I associate my website to .Net core version ? (5.0 or 6.0)

Thanks,
Venkat.

Comment: IIS's Integrated Pipeline setting only concerns .NET Framework applications, not .NET Core / .NET 5+ applications, The only thing that matters is that you have the `ASPNetCoreModuleV2` IIS Module installed (also note that `ASPNetCoreModuleV2` is used for .NET Core 2 and all later versions, yes, it's confusing).

Comment: How to check if these two modules in IIS? Or is there a way to check if they are correctly installed in the machine?

Comment: Isn't the **.NET 5 Hosting Bundle** installed? https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/5.0

Answer (score 0):

Its figured out. Looks like the ASP.NET core hosting is very simpler than expected.
All I had to was the following.

```
 0.First publish the files to a folder.
 1.Copy the published files to the root directory of the website.
 2.Install the ASP.Net core bundle version 6.0 and restart the machine.
```

and thats all... it works. no need to configure application pool or anything in the IIS server. Deploying the website is much easier in asp.net core.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).